# How do I customize the Content Security Policy (CSP) headers for each controller/action in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I have a large CSP configuration in `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb`, but there are some pages where I would like to send some slightly different headers. E.g. Allow all images from any source on a certain page.

Is there a built-in way to do this in Rails, or a gem I can use? Or should I just write some custom code to generate the header myself?

Comment: You can override the global settings on a per controller basis with [ActionController::ContentSecurityPolicy::ClassMethods#content_security_policy](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ContentSecurityPolicy/ClassMethods.html#method-i-content_security_policy). Its not terribly well documented but I think it yields the same kind of configuration object that you use in an initializer.

Comment: The options are [just `only:` and `except` which are passed to before_action](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-_normalize_callback_options).

Comment: I'm a bit too lazy to spin up an app right now and check how it works in detail so feel free to use this to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the global settings on a per controller basis with [ActionController::ContentSecurityPolicy::ClassMethods#content_security_policy](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ContentSecurityPolicy/ClassMethods.html#method-i-content_security_policy)

I also came up with my own method of configuring the `Content-Security-Policy` header. I [wrote a blog post about what I came up with](https://docspring.com/blog/posts/better-csp-configuration-for-rails/), and I released the code as a [Ruby gem called better_content_security_policy](https://rubygems.org/gems/better_content_security_policy) (and [on GitHub](https://github.com/DocSpring/better_content_security_policy).)

For example, I can now set up my CSP rules in a view partial, right next to the `javascript_include_tag` that needs them. I also prefer my DSL and I think it's slightly nicer to use.

Here's the view partial I use to set up Plausible Analytics (in `app/views/layouts/_plausible_analytics.html.haml`):

```
- if PLAUSIBLE_ANALYTICS_HOST
  - content_security_policy.connect_src PLAUSIBLE_ANALYTICS_HOST
  - content_security_policy.script_src PLAUSIBLE_ANALYTICS_HOST
  = javascript_include_tag "#{PLAUSIBLE_ANALYTICS_HOST}/js/script.js", defer: true, data: { domain: local_assigns[:domain].presence || request.host }
  = javascript_tag nonce: true do
    window.plausible = window.plausible || function() { (window.plausible.q = window.plausible.q || []).push(arguments) }
```